# typo3: trying to understand some extension codes

Tags: php, typo3

Almost in every typo3 extension file, there is this kind of code:

```
if (defined('TYPO3_MODE') && $TYPO3_CONF_VARS[TYPO3_MODE]['XCLASS']['ext/jc_job/pi1/class.tx_jcjob_pi1.php'])   
{
    include_once($TYPO3_CONF_VARS[TYPO3_MODE]['XCLASS']['ext/jc_job/pi1/class.tx_jcjob_pi1.php']);
}
```

Question:

what does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XLASSing is used in TYPO3 to register a class of yours to extend a class of the TYPO3 Core or any extension.
If your extension registers itself (by adding an entry to `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS[TYPO3_MODE]['XLCLASS']['path/to/the/file.php']`) the class instantiation mechanism (`t3lib_div::makeInstance` in TYPO3 version 4) creates the class with your implementation instead of the "default" one.

You can read more about XLCASSes in the [TYPO3 Wiki](http://wiki.typo3.org/XCLASS)

Be also aware that XLCASSing is the historic way and in TYPO3 6.0 you have to use the autoloader to register your classes (which is a much nicer way, as not every file has to be cluttered with the mentioned statements)

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised you are not using the TYPO3's documentation...

First hit with full description and samples: http://wiki.typo3.org/XCLASS

> XCLASS'ing is a mechanism in TYPO3 CMS to extend or overwrite classes
>   or methods of other extensions or of core code with own code...